# Prevent click event from mousedown

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I tried the following code on Chrome, Firefox and IE:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');

test.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
  alert( 'clicked' );
});

test.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function ( e ) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

In chrome, the alert will not be fired; in firefox and ie, yes. Which is the correct behaviour? How can I prevent the click event to be fired?

[jsBin Example](http://jsbin.com/ficizojivi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Huh, I'm using Chrome and the alert still fire. What exactly do you want to archieve?

Comment: @Passerby - Which wersion of Chrome do you have? My is `46.0.2490.80 m`

Comment: You could also add `e.preventDefault();`to mousedown. But now it works for me. Have you deleted cache and refreshed?

Comment: I see the alert on Chrome as well. Stop Propagation will only stop the mousedown event from bubbling up, not the click event.

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik Linux 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit)

Comment: There is any method (without variables) to prevent `click event` from the `mousedown event`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cancel the click event, you can do that in the Capture phase. Attach a click listener to the body to cancel the click event on the required element. The third argument in addEventListener lets you specify if you want to use the capture phase.

http://jsbin.com/kocapuharo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: The question was how to do it from the `mousedown` event. The `click` event fires on mouse button release, so it's not always possible to do the former when you can do the latter.

Answer (score 1):

There you go! Just run the snippet.

```js
const element = document.getElementById('test');
setupElement(element);

function setupElement(element){
    let clickedByMouse = false;

    element.onclick = (e) => {
        console.log(clickedByMouse);
        if(clickedByMouse){
          e.preventDefault();
        }else{
          doSomething();
          clickedByMouse = false;//reset clickByMouse if needed
        }
        console.log(clickedByMouse);
    }
    
    element.onmousedown = (e) => {
        clickedByMouse = true;
    }

}
```

```css
#test {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```